# What is the negative margin alternative in my case?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't want to use ***-margin*** in my code. What is the alternative? I know using negative values is not good for codes.
So what is the best and most simple method to avoid a negative margin?

[image]

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="content">col</div>
    </div>
  </div><br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content">col-6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="content">col-6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}


.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: -15px; **<<== it's the problem**
    margin-right: -15px; **<<== it's the problem**
}

.col {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.col-6 {
    max-width: 50%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.col,.col-6 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve layout-wise? You have a `.container` so if you need spacing on the sides of your elements use the padding you already have in place. Also, are you using Bootstrap for this? Those class names are usually associated with it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using negative margin in the way you are using them.

Comment: @AStombaugh I'm just learning CSS and just want to know what is the alternative to the negative margin? no, I'm not using Bootstrap